# Unexpected ref object when RadioButtons created from array

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm upgrading from React 15 to 16 and I'm getting this warning in my browser console

> Warning: Unexpected ref object provided for RadioButton. Use either a
>   ref-setter function or React.createRef().
>       in RadioButton (created by RadioButtonGroup)

for the following code:

```js
<RadioButtonGroup
  name="media"
  onChange={props.onChange}
>
  {projs.map(proj => (
    <RadioButton
      key={proj.id}
      label={proj.title}
      value={proj.value}
    />
  ))}
</RadioButtonGroup>
```

Can anyone help me understand why I get this warning when the RadioButtons are generated from an array but not if I wrote them manually, and how can I generate options correctly?

This is material-ui v0.20 and React 16.4. This did not happen with React 15.